# Iterate the every elements of arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have two arrays (3x3) and I want to access elements from both arrays as

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
y = [[11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19]]
z = stack((x, y))
```

Now I want subarrays such that I get

```
z1 = [1, 11]
z2 = [2, 12]
z3 = [3, 13]
z4 = [4, 14]
...
```

I tried `z[:, 0]` but it is not giving the `[1, 11]` as I want. I can write a `for` loop and iterate over `z[:, i][:, j]` but my actual arrays sizes are 6k x 6k, so it will be very slow. Is there any way to workaround? Thanks.

Comment: please, share your effort

Comment: What do you want to do with these subarrays? There is probably a vectorized solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
z[:, 0, 0]
>>> array([ 1, 11])
```

You missed the last index, since your stack is now 3-dimensional.

Now, if you want to access every element separately, you need to loop over 3 twice for `z[:, i, j]`.

---

If you catually just want to have an array with 2 dimensions, you have to flatten them first:

```
x_ = np.array(x).reshape(-1, 1)
y_ = np.array(y).reshape(-1, 1)

z = np.hstack((x_, y_))

z[0]
>>> array([ 1, 11])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
x=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
y=[[11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19]]

for i in zip(x,y):
    for j in zip(i[0], i[1]):
        print(list(j))
```

The output:

```
[1, 11]
[2, 12]
[3, 13]
[4, 14]
[5, 15]
[6, 16]
[7, 17]
[8, 18]
[9, 19]
```